# List of drives as string array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am working with a third party power-shell library. One of the function parameter in that library method is string array. This parameter value needs to contains the hard-disk drives. I have following script to retrieve the drives

```
[string[]] $drives = $null;
gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype = 3" | Select Name  | % { $drives +=  $_.Name   }
$drives -is [array]
Write-Output $drives
```

The output of this script is

> True
>   C:
>   D:

However third party library doesn’t seem to accept this as an array. If I hard code the drives as follows, then everything works.

```
$drives = @('C:', 'D:')
```

My question is that the way I am retrieving drives as form of string array is correct? Note that I need to work against Power-Shell 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-WMIObject` is returning a collection of `ManagementObject` objects, and your `Select-object` is selecting one property of them *for display*. IOW, you're already getting an array (do your `foreach-object` in the pipeline isn't necessary), you just need the right *kind* of array (a string, in this case).

If you pass the `-expandproperty` parameter to `select-object`, you'll get an array of strings (in this case) suitable for your needs.

```
$drives = get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype=3" | select-object -expandproperty name
write-output $drives
```

The output of your script as seen by the third-party library includes the output of `$drives -is [array]` (even though you don't explicitly use it in your script as shown here, `write-output` is implied), which is also causing it some consternation. Output that to a different stream ( like `Write-Verbose` or `write-debug`), or omit it altogether.

Comment: With this approach, the third party library function is giving me an error which basically implies that I am providing more arguments to function. Could this be because now I have additional spaces between drive letters? Also shouldn't the drive letter be in single quotes since its a string array?

Comment: Without knowing what that third-party library is, what it expects as input, or the precise error message, one can only guess. But I can tell you that `$drives` definitely contains an array of strings. They just might not be the strings you're looking for.